# Try use easeljs with excanvas or flashcanvas in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, easeljs, flashcanvas

I'm using easeljs in my webpage.

But when it show nothing in IE8.

I had added excanvas or flashcanvas to webpage, it show the same blank page.

Then i'm using IE11 debug tool to emulate IE8 and trying to debug.

The debugger say Object not support this method or attribute 'addEventListener' at Stage.js Line 526 (code is o.t.addEventListener(n, o.f, false);).

I trace in the code, and it show this method should exist.

Now i just want to figure out where is the problem, easeljs or flashcanvas.

here is my webpage  http://goo.gl/kcGVBO

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading this thread [https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/83](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/83), and decide if it is really worth the effort as your are going against the grain a bit. Then you may want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13478739/1842531) if you decide to continue on.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, i had viewed that artical, but not notice its the answer. Until you post it again.