# Svg animation with css - fallbacks IE

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

What is the best option of fallback IE non supporting issue on CSS/SVG animations ?

Comment: javascript:: [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/gsap) - [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/about/) -  [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) - and jQuery, or CSS spritesheets having SVG's frames

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep [@m_a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864597/m-a) answer checked, just wanted to explain all available options as as fallback for people reading the question later and looking for an answer.

Before listing all options currently available having a look at http://caniuse.com/#search=svg will see that *basic* support for SVG in IE9+ with this issue though

> IE9-11 desktop & mobile don't properly scale SVG files. [Adding height, width, viewBox, and CSS rules](http://codepen.io/tomByrer/pen/qEBbzw?editors=110) seem to be the best workaround.

so If you want to fallback IE9+ then you just keep using SVG, but for IE8 and below SVG file is not an option.

Also it is important to know the term "[Sprite Animation](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099)" <sup>(1)</sup> which basically represents a step-based animation showing a new slide or image in each step in fractions of the second, for smooth animation 20+ slides/second is better so that not to have quirky to human eyes.

### **1. CSS3 Animation and Transition:**

CSS3 animation and transition and also the transform property could be used for simple and basic animations applied on DOM elements other than SVG elements but it is not supported in IE9 and below. As well as animating [animated CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) it is possible to create "*sprite animation*" with CSS animation by making use of `steps()`  like in this [*CSS sprite animation*](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps) example.

---

### **2. JavaScript**

I've seen very complex javascript animation back in 2005 and 2006, and there was a website whose owner made two identical versions of the website one totally in Flash and the other totally in javascript -*which was slightly quirky though*- this is a very basic and [simple pure javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/g4cu599v/).

With javascript -*pure or jQuery*<sup>(2)</sup>- you can change CSS properties in general but mostly for simple animation you'll use properties like positioning, color changing and opacity.

As well as above implementing "sprite animation" is possible too like in [*these two examples*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/65w4cs0g/6/) which I just made to mimic the "*sprite animation*" example in the CSS part above applied first on background position property and second on an 'img' tag with its parent element having `overflow:hidden`. again the image is `.png` but you can use SVG in the same way if you're looking for a fallback for IE9+ only.

There are also other JS libraries<sup>(3)</sup> which could be used:

- [**Greensock**](https://greensock.com) with its [GSAP API](https://greensock.com/gsap), is a good option since it is fast and provide fallback back to IE6, also could work with other js libraries as well as CSS and canvas, I like the way [morphSVG](https://greensock.com/morphSVG) works too.
- [**CreateJS**](http://www.createjs.com/) [ [Easeljs](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs) and [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) ] which works with HTML canvas -*yeah right canvas are not [supported in](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/83)* IE8 *and below, there is a [workaround for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724404/getting-ie8-compatibility-with-easeljs-and-explorercanvas)* IE8 *thought*- and it provides exporting from flash files.
- [**Snap.svg**](http://snapsvg.io/) looks simple and nice and works with SVG means only IE9+ are supported, so if you want a fallback for IE8 and below you can't use this one.
- [**RaphaelJS**](http://raphaeljs.com/) supports very old browsers including IE6+ and it produces scale-able vector because uses the SVG W3C and VML<sup>(4)</sup> as DOM objects.
- [**Adobe Edge**](http://www.adobe.com/products/edge-animate.html) <sup>(5)</sup> lets you create HTML5 animation with an interface but I *think* it produces lots of javascript files. Also you can export from Edge to Snap.svg with some plugin I believe.

---

### 3. **Flash:**

Flash<sup>(6)</sup> was used as best option for web designers for creating cross-browser animation for almost a decade but gradually was abandoned due to presenting CSS3 animation and the revolution of javascript as well as the handheld devices which stopped supporting Flash since around 2012.

Flash creates vector based graphics and key-frames based animations as well as the ability to embedfonts as vector in times were verdana, tahoma and times new roman were default fonts of the web before [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), to have vector graphics you can use the drawing tools inside the program or import Adobe Illustrator `.ae` files.

You can use Flash as great fallback for IEs as it is supported since long time as well as it produces scale-able vector graphics just like SVG does and offers tweening but it has it's scripting language<sup>(7)</sup> which you mostly don't need unless if you want to offer interactions to the user, also -*as far as I know*- you can't access its structure with javascript.

Again for demonstration purposes I've also created this [*flash example*](http://www.fastswf.com/whM0bF8) which uses same "*sprite animation*" idea from the CSS part. Also created this *[vector graphics demo example](http://www.fastswf.com/xWvox4U)* .

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Upon a comment from the OP, for ***inline*** SVG, when DOM is ready -*put javascript right before the closing* `</body>` *tag*- you can do one of the following:

- Use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) <sup>(8)</sup> which detects individual features of the browser -*all browser not* IE *only*- to detect whether the browser supports [SVG features](https://modernizr.com/download?inlinesvg-svgclippaths-svgfilters-setclasses) - in the link I included "inlinesvg", "svgclippaths" and "svgfilters" features you can add or remove features - then hit build and download it, check [the documentation](https://modernizr.com/docs) to know how to use it.
- Detect if the browser is IE or not, I modified this [condepen](http://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN) and made this [*Demo Fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6es0jvqt/) <sup>(9)</sup> to make a condition so that *if it is IE and Version < 9* it replaces all inline `.svg` with the corresponding `.png`.
- There is this hack `<!--[if IE]> stuff here <![endif]-->`, used to work in older IE version, but not on IE10+ it won't work. so you can have this:

  ```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="repSVG.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  ```

Which basically means, if IE Less Than 9 -*hence the **lt*** letters- load **`repSVG.js`** which will contain only the replacement and the `replaceSVG()` function, check this [*Demo Fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ts6v4xgw/4/)

For SVG as ***backgrounds***, like if you're doing a "sprite animation", create another css file, say **`fix.css`**, which contains identical naming of all CSS rules that have `.svg` backgrounds, but with `.png` images instead, like:

in you **`style.css`**:

```
.foo {
  width:300px;
  height:120px;
  background:url(foo.svg);
  background-size:300px 120px;
}
.bar {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background:url(bar.svg);
  background-size:200px 50px;
}
```

in **`fix.css`** you have:

```
.foo { background:url(foo.png); }
.bar { background:url(bar.png); }
```

Then in the `head` section of your page do one of these:

- Use Modernizr to load the **`fix.css`** in the `head` if the browser *doesn't* support SVG as backgrounds.
- Again you can use this easy thing:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main-style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fix.css">
  <![endif]-->
  ```
- Use same logic in the [*Previous Fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6es0jvqt/) to detect if browser is IE and version is less that a certain version, then load **`fix.css`** again in the `head` section.

Note that you need to make sure to have the method you chose from above *after* you load **`style.css`** so that when you load **`fix.css`** it will override the `background-image` properties of **`style.css`**.

<sup>(*)</sup> Check [CSS-Tricks: Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to [@kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) for mentioning [SMIL](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)<sup>(10)</sup> with a polyfill, SMIL is a great option for SVG animation but the reason I didn't think it is an option it is because [IE never adopted it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil), IE relied on its VML, this why I didn't think it would suit the OP.

Again thanks to [@kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido),I didn't know about this [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) which is:

> SMIL implementation written in ECMAScript ... It is primarily targeted to SVG animations... FakeSmile makes declarative animations work in IE too.

However, I'm not sure if this fix will work in new versions of chrome, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL):

> Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations.

Also from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)

> **Update December 2015:** At the time of this update, SMIL seems to be kinda dying. Sarah Drasner [has a guide](https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/) on how you can replace some of it's features.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>. [Examples of spritesheet images](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=633&q=spritesheet&oq=spritesheet&gs_l=img.3..0i10l2j0j0i10l3j0i10i30l3j0i5i30.922.922.0.1826.1.1.0.0.0.0.216.216.2-1.1.0....0...1ac..64.img..0.1.215.QBujB_mnizE)

<sup>(2)</sup>. jQuery animation is slow compared to pure javascript animation, GSAP, or Createjs.

<sup>(3)</sup>. I've seen Greensock, EaselJS and Snap.svg in action but not for complex animation though just simple things similar to CSS3 animation.

<sup>(4)</sup>. [Vector Markup Language (VML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217(v=vs.85).aspx) is an XML-based markup used by Microsoft and is supported in IE5 - IE8 but is deprecated since the realese of IE9. it is also supported in MS Office 2000 and later.

<sup>(5)</sup>. [Adobe Edge showcase examples.](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/showcase.html)

<sup>(6)</sup>. As well as flash there are other software used to create `.swf` flash files but most of them don't offer rich features except [SWiSH Max](http://www.swishzone.com/index.php?area=products&product=max) which offers good level of features.

<sup>(7)</sup>. [ActionScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) is the scripting language used in Flash and it is ECMAScript syntax like javascript.

<sup>(8)</sup>. Using feature detection is better than browser detection, because say someone uses an old browser other than IE, for example Safari5 or Opera12 then [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6es0jvqt/) won't fix it because it detects IE or not only not if the browser supports SVG or not.

<sup>(9)</sup>. If you open the fiddle in any browser other than IE8 and below it will show SVG otherwise it show PNG, to experiment it change this `IEversion < 9` to `IEversion < 14` and you'll see this affect all IE existing IE in the time of this post. Notice that, in case later Microsoft decided to release an IE version that supports SVG animation with CSS, presumeably IE16, you can make another condition for that, something like this [*demo fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/kp44kz18/1/).

<sup>(10)</sup>. SMIL stands for Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language, it has an XML-based syntax just like SVG, [SVG animation using SMIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_animation#SVG_animation_using_SMIL)

Comment: @Mi-Creativy : Thank you for your great detailed answer. Is there any option to use my svg animation css, and just in IE to show any image instead of the svg element.

Comment: @YakyRefael, you welcome.. "*and just in IE to show any image instead of the svg element*" this is a whole story itself, check the **update** section in my updated answer.

Comment: Really detailed answer, but you don't even talk about SMIL ??? I mean, if you want to do SVG Animations, there is a whole part about it in the specs. A way lot easier to implement than coding. IE never supported SMIL, but with [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) polyfill, you can do a lot more than with CSS, which is really, really limited.

Comment: @Kaiido, I've never heard of fakeSmile all I know was SMIL not working with IE and the OP is looking for a fallback for IEs so didn't think SMIL is an option. I apologize

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, that's too bad you never heard of it, it enables most of SMIL animations in browsers that don't support it (IE being the first target). So IMO, SMIL+fakeSmile is more than an option, it's just a way better way to go than CSS itself.

Comment: I wouldn't go for CSS  either I see GSAP or snap.svg, flash as fallback more comfy for me, I'll Update my answer to include your suggestion, thanks for telling me something new to know

Comment: Does SMIL work for Chrome 45+ considering fakesmile?? because "*Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations.*"

Answer (score 1):

IE (at least until IE11 -- which is the most used version) does not support CSS3 SVG animations. See: [CSS3 animation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302615/css3-animation-is-not-working).

Javascript is available, at a cost to performance, and certainly a cost of time and flexibility. Animated GIFs could support something simple and self-contained. The first answer in the above link has more about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24477055/1864597

Comment: Animated GIFs can't be an option because it is not Scale-able Vector Graphics

Comment: That's true if scalability is a must.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Well, it's a fallback - not a perfect alternative

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, the OP is looking for a fallback for "SVG Animation" not "SVG" fallback

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Do you have another ideas like gif fallback . and if so, What is the shortcode ? Thank you allot

Comment: The only time you'll need some other format rather than svg is when you're willing to target IE8 and below, for IE9+ you can *ALL* use the libraries I suggested in the comment on your question, or you can use [CSS sprite sheet animations with steps technique](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps) which can applied to SVG -*IE9+*- or JPG, PNG, GIF, which I consider better than GIF animation if it used with PNG since in png pixels have alpha channel which can be multi-levels semi-transparent as well as being fully transparent or fully opaque

Comment: While in GIF pixels is either 100% opaque or 100% transparent, another benefit is that GIF only support 256 colors max while PNG has way way way more than that, millions I believe. so instead of GIF animation use css sprite sheet with steps if you can with SVG for IE9+ or PNG for IE8-

Comment: Another great option for IE8 and below -*even for modern versions of* IE- is Flash animation which is vector graphic and scale-able. But remember that you still can use GSAP, Raphael.js Snap.svg and jQuery to animate DOM elements like divs or spans - *and SVG for* IE9+ - and they all fallback to IE6, except Snap.svg which works on IE9+ only